# matching strings in scala

Tags: string, scala

I am trying to create a method that takes a list of lists (which reads from a csv file), and a string, and outputs a list of all the data that has that string.

Data example:

```
"Joe, 14,1989"
"John, 13,1999"
"Mary, 10, 2000"
```

the function I have is this:

```
def name(info: List[List[String]], str: String): List[List[String]] = 
info.filter(lst =>lst.head.toString == str)
```

However, I get an empty list in return. What is the best way to compare  strings in scala?

Comment: Is `info.head` supposed to be `List("joe","14","1989")`? b/c yes `"joe" == "joe"` in scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling `.head`, this will return only lists whose first element is equal to `str`. (It's also superfluous to call `.toString`, since the items are already strings.)

What you want is `info.filter(lst => lst.contains(str))`, or simply `info.filter(_.contains(str))`.